# Fetching rets property data using PHrets plugin

Tags: php

I am building realestate app. I have not found any official rets api documents online to help me.  I want to fetch rets property listing. i am using PHRETS Plugin,I have install PHRETS version 2.6 but i am tried to get property listing.Please check it out.

error message:

> Array (
> [message] => SimpleXMLElement Object
> (
> [0] => Invalid Class Type
> )
>
> ```
> [code] => 20203 );
> ```

```
<?php
//here my code : 
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$log = new \Monolog\Logger('PHRETS');
$log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG));

$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('here my rets login url')
        ->setUsername('here my rets username')
        ->setPassword('here my rets password')
        ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');
        // $config->setLoginUrl('http://retsgw.flexxmls.com/rets2_3/Login')
        // ->setUsername('demomls.rets.phrets')
        // ->setPassword('DEMO_PASSWORD');
       // ->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');

$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
$rets->setLogger($log);

$connect = $rets->Login();

$system = $rets->GetSystemMetadata();
echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($system);

$resources = $system->getResources();
$classes = $resources->first()->getClasses();
//var_dump($classes);

$classes = $rets->GetClassesMetadata('Property');
//print_r($classes->first());

$objects = $rets->GetObject('Property', 'Photo', '00-1669', '*', 1);
//print_r($objects);

$fields = $rets->GetTableMetadata('Property', 'A');
print_r($fields[0]);

$results = $rets->Search('Property', 'A', '*', ['Limit' => 3, 'Select' => 'LIST_1,LIST_105,LIST_15,LIST_22,LIST_87,LIST_133,LIST_134']);
foreach ($results as $r) {
    print_r($r);
}
```

Comment: Use Class type Property at the place of RES